# How can I make my solution to "Climbing the Leaderboard" not time out?

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I tried to solve [the following challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem) and optimize the solution but my code still times out. My code is below.

## Problem statement

> ### Climbing the Leaderbord
>
> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the
>   leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. The game uses [Dense
>   Ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Dense_ranking_.28.221223.22_ranking.29),
>   so its leaderboard works like this:
>
> - The player with the highest score is ranked number 1 on the leaderboard.
> - Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.
>
> For example, the four players on the leaderboard have high scores of
>   100, 90, 90, and 80. Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2, and 3,
>   respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80 and 105, her rankings after
>   each game are 4th, 3rd and 1st.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the `climbingLeaderboard` function in the editor below. It
>   should return an integer array where each element \$res[j]\$
>   represents Alice's rank after the \$j^{th}\$ game.
>
> `climbingLeaderboard` has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `scores`: an array of integers that represent leaderboard scores
> - `alice`: an array of integers that represent Alice's scores
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer \$n\$, the number of players on the
>   leaderboard. The next line contains \$n\$ space-separated integers
>   \$scores[i]\$, the leaderboard scores in decreasing order. The next
>   line contains an integer, \$m\$, denoting the number games Alice
>   plays. The last line contains \$m\$ space-separated integers
>   \$alice[j]\$, the game scores.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - \$1 \le n \le 2 \times 10^5\$
> - \$1 \le m \le 2 \times 10^5\$
> - \$0 \le scores[i] \le 10^9\$ for \$0 \le i \lt n\$
> - \$0 \le alice[j] \le 10^9\$ for \$0 \le j \lt m\$
> - The existing leaderboard, \$scores\$, is in descending order.
> - Alice's scores, \$alice\$, are in ascending order.
>
> #### Subtask
>
> For 60% of the maximum score:
>
> - \$1 \le n \le 200\$
> - \$1 \le m \le 200\$
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Print \$m\$ integers. The \$j^{th}\$ integer should indicate Alice's
>   rank after playing the \$j^{th}\$ game.
>
> <sup>From [*Climbing the Leaderboard*](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem) on HackerRank.com</sup>.

## My code

The code simply starts with `climbingLeaderboard` method below which delete all similar values in the scores array,
after that it start with Alice score and using binary search it return the correct position.

```
int getPosition(vector<int> scores,int value,int start,int end){

    int middle = (start+end)/2;

    if(scores[start]<value){
        return start;
    }else if(scores[end]>value){
        return end+1;
    }

    else if(scores[middle]==value){
        return middle;
    }
    else if(start==end){
        if(scores[start]>value){
            return start+1;
        }else{
            return start;
        }
    }

    else if(scores[middle]>value){
        return getPosition(scores,value,middle+1,end);
    }else{
        return getPosition(scores,value,start,middle-1);
    }

}
/////
/////

vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(vector<int> scores, vector<int> alice) {

    int i=1;
    while(1){
        if(i == scores.size()){
            break;
        }
        if(scores[i]==scores[i-1]){
            scores.erase(scores.begin() + i);
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    vector<int> results;
    int endValue = scores.size()-1;

    for(int j=0;j<alice.size();j++){
        endValue = getPosition(scores,alice[j],0,endValue);
        results.insert(results.end(),endValue+1);
    }

    return results;

    }
```

Any ideas? How can I make it not time out?

Comment: Also, it would be nice if the code can compile on its own, which requires the necessary `#include`s and other things (which I prefer not to guess).

Answer (score 1):

\$\DeclareMathOperator{\Oh}{O}\$Frankly, the code in the HackerRank editor is a large mess.  It is promoting crap like `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`, and the code contains many problems: `int` for traversing a `std::vector`, copying containers around, etc.  Not to mention bad practices like `i++`, explicitly calling `fout.close()`, not using standard algorithm, etc.  It really shouldn't be like that.

In your code, the whole `getPosition` function is redundant.  Use `std::lower_bound` instead.  And since `std::vector::erase` is \$\Oh(n)\$, the code is \$\Oh(n^2)\$, which is unnecessary inefficient.

The problem is very simple and can be finished in several lines without sacrificing readability:

```
using score_t = long;
using rank_t = long;

// scores is passed by value to take advantage of possible optimization.
rank_t get_rank(std::vector<score_t> scores, score_t alice_score)
{
    scores.erase(std::unique(scores.begin(), scores.end()), scores.end());

    auto it = std::lower_bound(scores.begin(), scores.end(), alice_score, std::greater<>{});
    return it - scores.begin() + 1;
}
```

The code is \$\Oh(n)\$ and I don't think you can do better.  Note that each score of Alice's is independent, so it makes no sense to process them together in a function.  I used `long` because the problem seems to require numbers as large as \$10^9\$.  `scores` will be modified in the function, so instead of making a copy manually, we let the compiler do so for us in the parameter list.  This enables possible optimization opportunities.

Here, we used two standard algorithms:

- `std::unique`, which "removes" adjacent equal elements.  Standard algorithms cannot change the size of `scores` via iterators, so `std::unique` makes sure that the first \$N\$ elements are the result, where \$N\$ is the number of elements in the result.  The rest of the elements are placed in a valid but otherwise unspecified state.  Then, we call `erase` to erase these garbage elements.  This is also known as the [remove-erase idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799314).
- `std::lower_bound`, which performs a binary search and returns the first element that compares not "less" than the provided value.  By default, "less" is defined by `<`, thus operating on an ascending sequence.  In this case, we use `std::greater<>` to define "less" by `>`, so that `std::lower_bound` is adapted to work on a descending sequence.

---

Now let's go through your code: (regardless of whether the code is what hackerrank gives you)

```
int getPosition(vector<int> scores,int value,int start,int end){
```

As I said, this function is provided by the standard library and you shouldn't be reinventing your own without a good reason.  If you want to see how the standard version looks like, there is an example implementation at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).

---

```
vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(vector<int> scores, vector<int> alice) {
```

As I said before, this function is illogical.  It should handle one Alice-score at a time.  Also, `climbingLeaderboard` isn't really a good function name.

Passing `scores` by value is justified because you modify it in the functions, but passing `alice` by value introduces an unnecessary copy.  It should be passed by const reference instead.  And `int` is not only a magic type, but also a type that is not sufficiently large here.

---

```
int i=1;
while(1){
    if(i == scores.size()){
        break;
    }
    if(scores[i]==scores[i-1]){
        scores.erase(scores.begin() + i);
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

**Space.**  Also, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `while (1)` loop here: you are obfuscating the code by refusing to place the condition in the proper place.  And `int` isn't the correct type to use here.  Use `size_type` (or at least a named type).  `++i` should be used instead of `i++` in a discarded value expression.

And you are essentially reimplementing the \$\Oh(n)\$ `std::unique` in a \$\Oh(n^2)\$ way.  Just use the standard algorithm and avoid reinventing the wheel.

---

```
vector<int> results;
int endValue = scores.size()-1;
```

In this particular case, we know that `!scores.empty()`, but storing the result in a `int` is still inadvisable.  Use `auto` or `std::vector<int>::size_type`.

---

```
for(int j=0;j<alice.size();j++){
    endValue = getPosition(scores,alice[j],0,endValue);
    results.insert(results.end(),endValue+1);
}
```

Again, space.  And `++j` not `j++`.  And the third line is just

```
results.push_back(endValue + 1);
```

There is no reason to use `insert` + iterator here.

---

```
    return results;

    }
```

Is the weird indentation a copy-paste problem?

Comment: Why Would i++ be Bad Practice?

Comment: Since the vector given is sorted in descending order, `lower_bound` doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: @tinstaafl that's exactly when the generality and flexibility of STL comes to play -- in this case, you use `greater`.

Comment: @RyanStone Unless you need the pre-increment value, the copy involved is useless. And while that is harmless at least for small trivial types if the operation is inlined, it's a bad habit to have due to the compiler not being able to fix it for you in more complex cases, with less optimisation, or with insufficient information.