# Hacker Rank Climbing The Leaderboard

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, complexity

This has been asked a couple of times but here is my implementation in C++. I have 11/12 solutions completed. The 6th test case which has 200000 intial scores and Alice has even more scores causes my program to timeout. Below is the problem statement and the code. My question is, am I missing something in code complexity, or is this a more of a C++ optimization I need to add to get the last test data set through?

> **Problem**
>
> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. The game uses
>   Dense Ranking, so its leaderboard works like this:
>
> The player with the highest score is ranked number 1 on the
>   leaderboard. Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking
>   number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following
>   ranking number. For example, the four players on the leaderboard have
>   high scores of , , , and . Those players will have ranks 100, 90, 90,
>   and 80, respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80 and 105, her
>   rankings after each game are 4th, 3rd and 1st.
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the climbingLeaderboard function in the editor below. It should return an integer array where each element
>   `res[j]` represents Alice's rank after the `j`-th game.
>
> climbingLeaderboard has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `scores`: an array of integers that represent leaderboard scores
> - `alice`: an array of integers that represent Alice's scores
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer `n`, the number of players on the leaderboard. The next line contains `n` space-separated
>   integers `scores[i]`, the leaderboard scores in decreasing order. The
>   next line contains an integer, `m`, denoting the number games Alice
>   plays. The last line contains `m` space-separated integers `alice[j]`, the
>   game scores.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> The existing leaderboard, scores, is in descending order. Alice's scores, alice, are in ascending order.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print `m` integers. The `j`-th integer should indicate Alice's rank after playing the  `j`-th game.

**Code**

```
std::vector<int>::iterator m_binary_search(std::vector<int>::iterator begin,
  std::vector<int>::iterator end, int score)
{
  std::vector<int>::iterator ret;

  if (score > (*begin)) {
    return begin;
  } else if (score < (*(end - 1))) {
    return end - 1;
  }

  if (*begin == score) {
    ret = begin;
  } else if (*(end - 1) == score) {
    ret = end - 1;
  } else if (begin + 1 == end) {
    ret = begin;
  } else {
    std::ptrdiff_t middle = std::distance(begin, end) / 2;
    if (*(begin + middle) == score) {
      ret = begin + middle;
    } else if ((score < (*begin)) && (score > * (begin + middle))) {
      ret = m_binary_search(begin, begin + middle, score);
    } else {
      ret = m_binary_search(begin + middle, end, score);
    }
  }

  return ret;
}

// Complete the climbingLeaderboard function below.
std::vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(
  const std::vector<int> &scores,
  const std::vector<int> &alice)
{
  std::vector<int> rankBuckets;
  for (std::size_t s = 0; s < scores.size();) {
    int curr = scores[s];
    while (s < scores.size() && scores[s] == curr) {
      ++s;
    }
    rankBuckets.push_back(curr);
  }

  typedef std::vector<int>::iterator VectIt_t;
  std::vector<int> ranks;
  for (int score : alice) {
    VectIt_t cit = m_binary_search(
      rankBuckets.begin(),
      rankBuckets.end(),
      score);
    VectIt_t nit = cit;
    ++nit;

    std::ptrdiff_t rank = std::distance(rankBuckets.begin(), cit);

    if (nit == rankBuckets.end()) {
      if (*cit != score) {
        rankBuckets.push_back(score);
        rank += 2;
      } else {
        rank += 1;
      }
      ranks.push_back(rank);
      continue;
    }

    int crank = *cit;
    int nrank = *nit;

    if (score > crank) {
      rankBuckets.insert(cit, score);
      rank += 1;
    } else if (score == crank) {
      rank += 1;
    } else if (score < crank && score > nrank) {
      rankBuckets.insert(nit, score);
      rank += 2;
    }

    ranks.push_back(rank);
  }
  return ranks;
}
```

Comment: Could you please copy the text of the programming challenge into this question. Links often go bad over time. I know you didn't write main, but some reviewers may want to see it to show how the code gets used.

Comment: Unlike stackoverflow you don't have to worry about a duplicate question in this case because everyone codes differently and as you pointed out the other times this question was posted it was in different languages.

Comment: @pacmaninbw question updated as per your request.

Answer (score 3):

(Adapted from my [answer to *How can I make my solution to “Climbing the Leaderboard” not time out?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/226309))

It is nice that you used `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`.  However, `int` is still directly used for the score.  I would prefer an alias:

```
using score_t = long;
using rank_t = long;
```

(Note that `int` is not guaranteed to have \$10^9\$.)

The `m_binary_search` function is redundant because we have `std::lower_bound` which should be optimized better.

The `climbingLeaderboard` is *way* too long.  The function is illogical. It should handle one Alice-score at a time. Also, `climbingLeaderboard` isn't really a good function name.  (I know HackerRank forces you to code sub-optimally sometimes, but you should be aware.)

The problem is very simple and can be finished in several lines without sacrificing readability:

```
using score_t = long;
using rank_t = long;

// scores is passed by value to take advantage of possible optimization.
rank_t get_rank(std::vector<score_t> scores, score_t alice_score)
{
    scores.erase(std::unique(scores.begin(), scores.end()), scores.end());

    auto it = std::lower_bound(scores.begin(), scores.end(), alice_score, std::greater<>{});
    return it - scores.begin() + 1;
}
```

The code is \$O(n)\$ and I don't think you can do better in terms of asymptotic analysis. Note that each score of Alice's is independent, so it makes no sense to process them together in a function. I used `long` because the problem seems to require numbers as large as \$10^9\$. `scores` will be modified in the function, so instead of making a copy manually, we let the compiler do so for us in the parameter list. This enables possible optimization opportunities.

Here, we used two standard algorithms:

- `std::unique`, which "removes" adjacent equal elements. Standard algorithms cannot change the size of `scores` via iterators, so `std::unique` makes sure that the first \$N\$ elements are the result, where \$N\$ is the number of elements in the result. The rest of the elements are placed in a valid but otherwise unspecified state. Then, we call erase to erase these garbage elements. This is also known as the [remove-erase idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799314).
- `std::lower_bound`, which performs a binary search and returns the first element that compares not "less" than the provided value. By default, "less" is defined by `<`, thus operating on an ascending sequence. In this case, we use `std::greater<>` to define "less" by `>`, so that `std::lower_bound` is adapted to work on a descending sequence.

Of course, you will need to adapt to HackerRank's strange interface, but that should be trivial.

Comment: I see your point about `int` versus `long` even though most computers today would default to a 64 bit int rather than a 32 bit int, but why `alias long`?

Comment: @pacmaninbw I don't really like directly seeing `long` ...  IMO, "This number represents a score" is better than "This number represents a long".

Comment: I understand, I read declarations different then you, "This long represents a score".

Comment: @pacmaninbw I get your point.  Anyway, sometimes it is inconvenient to introduce a declarator (e.g., `std::pair<score_t, rank_t>`), so I prefer encoding this information in the type specifier.  But I'd say it's a matter of style

Comment: I can see where that might make the code more readable, also easier to modify.

Comment: @L.F. I implemented your suggestions and then profiled the code. After get_rank is called. You have to update scores if alice's score is not found in leader board. Due to the fact that they provide a vector and `std::lower_bound` only works on `RandomAccessIterators` I am taking a performance hit in the insertion. Insertion into a vector is O(n) because you have to copy all the data. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan Insertion?  As far as I can see, all Alice-scores are independent of each other.  You don't need to insert anything.